# php - proxy - парсинг

Tags: php, proxy

Возникла необходимость парсинга по задаче(данные ИКС сайтов, количество страниц в индексе и т.д.). До этого никогда таким не занимался. 
В виду ограничений на количество запросов со стороны пользователя пришел к необходимости использования прокси для этой задачи.
Для парсинга использую библиотеку PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Вопрос - как использовать прокси для запроса к ресурсу?

Перепробовал множество вариантов, остановился на использовании библиотеки GuzzleHttp , но снова столкнулся с различными ошибками при попытки использовать прокси.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://vk-book.ru/my-ip.php', ["proxy" => "http://163.172.182.164:3128",
]);
echo $response->getBody();
```

В данном случае выдает ошибку

> 2020/02/20 16:24:51 [error] 940#940: *761 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 56: Received HTTP
>   code 407 from proxy after CONNECT (see
>   https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in
>   /var/www/w/seo/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:201

Пробовал разные прокси и разные варианты передачи прокси в параметры, но ни 1 не сработал.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно для прокси нужен логин и пароль

```
["proxy" => "http://username:password@163.172.182.164:3128"]
```

или сами прокси не очень, попробовать платный

или убрать запятую в массиве

```
["proxy" => "http://username:password@163.172.182.164:3128",]
["proxy" => "http://username:password@163.172.182.164:3128"]
```